# How to filter by OData nested dynamic property?

Tags: odata

I have an open type entity that is accessed by `foo.net/items`.
The entity is defined as:

```
<EntityType Name="myEntity" OpenType="true">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="name" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="name" Type="string" />
</EntityType>
```

An entity instance may look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "location": {
    "country": "USA"
  }
}
```

How can I reference the country property in my filter odata option? Is this the correct approach?
`foo.net/items?$filter=location/country ne null and location/country eq 'USA'`.

I believe the above is correct because it is a valid way to reference a property as per the ABNF in OData V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference nested property by `parentProperty/childProperty`.

In your case is not necessary to check if nested property in not null, so you can simplify the query like this:

```
foo.net/items?$filter=location/country eq 'USA'
```